# How can I read in a CSV into an R Variable and have it treated the same as using variable <- C(....)?

Tags: r

I have two CSV files with data like this:

```
3,5,1,4,3,5
```

I am trying to do the Mann-Whitney U test, but when I read in the two CSV files into variables "group1" and "group2", I get the message:

```
> # Performing the Mann-Whitney U test
> test_result <- wilcox.test(group1, group2, exact = FALSE)
Error in wilcox.test.default(group1, group2, exact = FALSE) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Reading the data directly in the R Script works fine, like this:

```
group1 <- c(3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5)
group2 <- c(4, 9, 6, 2, 1,9)
```

So, my question is how can I import the data from CSV files and have the variables be the same as using the "c" notation directly above (so the Mann-Whitney will work)?

Here is my R script:

```
# Example data for two groups
group1 <- read.csv("/Users/..../group1.csv", header = FALSE, colClasses = "integer", sep=",")
group2 <- read.csv("/Users/..../group2.csv", header = FALSE, colClasses = "integer", sep=",")

#group1 <- c(3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 5)
#group2 <- c(4, 9, 6, 2, 1,9)

# Performing the Mann-Whitney U test
test_result <- wilcox.test(group1, group2, exact = FALSE)

# Displaying the test results
print(test_result)

# To specifically display the U statistic, p-value, and related ranks, you can access them as follows:
cat("U statistic:", test_result$statistic, "\n")
cat("P-value:", test_result$p.value, "\n")

# For ranks, since the Mann-Whitney U test in R does not directly return ranks of the two samples,
# you can compute them separately if needed using the rank function on the combined data
combined_data <- c(group1, group2)
ranks <- rank(combined_data)
cat("Ranks:", ranks, "\n")
```

Thanks for all suggestions how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably just have to convert your data to numeric, e.g.

```
group1 <- as.numeric(group1)
group2 <- as.numeric(group2)
```

As kindly added by @robert-hacken, you should investigate why you got string values in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing the following, but probably the same result: "test_result <- wilcox.test(as.numeric(group1), as.numeric(group2), exact = FALSE)"

Comment: yes, same exact thing.

Comment: @Morkus I would definitely advise caution here and to check how your data was read and what you get from `as.numeric()`. It might not always be what you expect, e.g. `as.numeric(factor(c('1', '2', '11')))` happily gives you `c(1, 3, 2)`. The fact that some data you expected to be numeric is not numeric is a red flag and you should always do more than just blindly apply `as.numeric`.